# Applying stash in a local branch

Tags: git

I have created a local branch by:

```
          git checkout -b "something"
```

Now I want to apply my stash onto it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stash doesn't care what branch you are on, so just `git stash pop` as usual

Comment: I mean if I do "stash apply" it'll apply the changes to master i want to apply to this branch  - I am total noob in git : (

Comment: no. If you do stash apply it will apply to your current working copy, which is this branch.

Comment: oh ok...if I am checked out with my local branch and do "git stash apply" it ill apply the changes to the branch?? right?